# Arrays in EJS returning undefined and null value in NodeJS - Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, ejs

This is my ejs code

```
<% var tag = [''] %>
<form action="/like" method="POST">
    <% for (var i in tag){%>
        Tag: <input type="text" name="likes[]" value="<%= tag[i].likes %>"/><br><br>
             <button type="submit" value="accept">Send Tag</button><br><br><hr>
    <%} %>
</form>
```

This is my controller.js code

```
control.post('/like', (req, res, next) => {
    let tags = [req.body.likes];
    console.log(tags);
    iglike(tags);
    next();
    res.send(tags);
     
});
```

When I remove the `[]` from the `name = "likes[]"` the code returns the entered data perfectly.

But on `name = "likes[]"`  the code returns `undefined`  in the console log.

For example:
With likes[]

```
Input : App, Web

Output: [null] , In Console: Undefined
```

Without likes[]

```
Input: app, web
Output: ['app, web'] ( Stores them into single array)
```

I want my output to be

```
Input: app, example, thanks
Output: ['app','example','thanks']
```

I am using EJS view engine and node-express
i have added the `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))` code in my app.js too.

Comment: `tag` is an array of strings not an array of objects, `likes` wont be defined, change `<%= tag[i].likes %>` to `<%= tag[i] %>`

Comment: I tried but it still shows the same.

Comment: I think it needs to be `extended: true` to use arrays with body-parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change extended to true:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

And remove square brackets from req.body.likes:

```js
let tags = req.body.likes;
```